# Finitely connected planar domains and certain smooth maps with integrable Wirtinger derivative

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $D$  be a finitely connected, bounded domain in $\mathbb C$. Suppose that the boundary of $D$ consists of finitely many, pairwise disjoint, piecewise $C^1$-Jordan curves.  Does there exist  an exhaustion   sequence $(K_n)$ of compacta in $D$
with $K_n\subseteq K_{n+1}^\circ$ and $C^1$-maps $\phi_n:\mathbb C\to [0,1]$ such that $\phi_n=1$ on $K_n$, $\phi_n=0$ on $\mathbb C\setminus K_{n+1}$ and
$$\iint_D|\overline\partial \phi_n| dx dy\leq C$$ for every $n$.